# jquery .each() and $.post() works only for 1 element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to grab all of my class "reserved" (there are table cells). I want to send every cell's ID via jquery $.post() into some php method. Here is my JQuery code:

```
var cell_id;
$('.reserved').each(function()
{
    cell_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post("/controller/method/",{id: cell_id},function(data,status,xhr)
    {
        if(status=="success")
        {
        }
    })
});
```

It works perfectly if only one cell has class reserved, but when there are more than just one - it doesn't work at all!

Comment: This seems like it would send one post request per table cell.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work at all!" mean?

Comment: .reserved is class of table or table cells? post your html also

Comment: @AspiringAqib it's a cell class IIUC the description.

Comment: Any reason for declaring cell_id where you do? I'm wondering if there is a problem with closures in that it is only ever calling it with a single cell_id...

Comment: Your example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pyMAs/

Comment: @Chris This will matter only if it's used within the callback. Still doesn't make sense to declare it where it is.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Cool. I wasn't sure if the `each` might do something special causing problems. As it is Stefan seems to have demosntrated the code works fine so I'm going to stop worrying about it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send all id values using only a single call you need a different approach:

```
var cells = [];

$('.reserved').each(function() {
    cells.push(this.id);
}
$.post("/controller/method/",{ids: cells},function(data,status,xhr) {
    if(status=="success")
    {
    }
});
```

This builds one list of id values that you can then send to PHP (I'm assuming you're using that) as `$_POST['ids']` using a single call; AJAX requesta are expensive, so it's best to keep them to a minimum.

Comment: This assumes the receiver is PHP. If this doesn't work, you'll need to JSONify the post.

Comment: @JanDvorak That's true, it's an assumption, I've made that clear in my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You have a shared global variable called `cell_id` that doesn't seem to serve any purpose. Just get rid of it:

```
$('.reserved').each(function()
{
    $.post("/controller/method/",{id: $(this).attr('id')},function(data,status,xhr)
    {
        if(status=="success")
        {
        }
    })
});
```